# vscode: Api call for inserting newline respecting the indentation

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am looking for vscode API call for inserting newline respecting the indentation

[image]

Something like this...

`vscode.commands.executeCommand("cursorDown");
// this just puts the cursor in the next line`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`editor.action.insertLineAfter`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_basic-editing) command. I tried it with the command palette using vscode 1.22.2 and it does what your gif shows.

Comment: For anyone who is confused on how to use the command through the API, we have to use it like this vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.insertLineAfter');